# R dbGetQuery insert blob data with other text data

Tags: sql, r, database, sqlite

```r
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbExecute(db , "create table if not exists drug_rank (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    pertData_type text,
    pertData_name text,
    pathway_name text,
    drug_name text,
    drug_rank_RData blob
    )"
    )
```

I want to insert the data using a prepared statement. I have all the `drug_rank_RData` saved as `.RData`, which essentially is a `list`, I want to put them all in the database. How can I do so?

I tried the following but does not work:

```r
df <- list(a =c(1, 2,3), b = c(2, 4, 6), c = c(3, 6, 9)) |> as.data.frame()
drug_rank_obj <- list(sig_drugs = df, name = "test_drug_rank_obj")
dbGetQuery(db,
    "insert into drug_rank values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    params = list(
        1,
        "test type",
        "test name",
        "test pathway",
        "test drugname",
        drug_rank_obj
    )
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. An `rdata` file in binary file that holds a bunch of R objects on disk. That is very different than a list or data.frame in your current working environment. Do you have a file on disk and you want to move the binary contents in to the table? Or do you somehow want to convert live objects into binary data?

Comment: Maybe this guide will help you: https://jfaganuk.github.io/2015/01/12/storing-r-objects-in-sqlite-tables/

Comment: @MrFlick there are quite a few .rdata file, but they are generated by a program, inside each of them they only contain a list. I need to deploy the app but with the current .rdata amount I m not allowed to do so. So I think of using a database to reduce the number of .rdata file. For the guide you suggested, I understand that its relevance but the gist is that I have no idea how to insert both text and blob together as a row. While the guide only showed the blob case.. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only issue is that you need to serialize your data into a binary format in order to insert it into a blog. This example should work

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbExecute(db , "create table if not exists drug_rank (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    name text,
    object blob)"
)

# serialize data to binary
drug_rank_obj <- list(a =c(1, 2,3), b = c(2, 4, 6), c = c(3, 6, 9)) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> serialize(NULL)

# insert into data base
dbExecute(db,
    "insert into drug_rank values (?, ?, ?)",
    params = list(1, "my data", list(drug_rank_obj))
)

## retrieve data
rows <- dbGetQuery(db, "select * from drug_rank where _id==?",
            params=list(1))

## un-serialize data into object
data <- unserialize(rows$object[[1]])
```

When doing an insert, use `dbExecute` rather than `dbGetQuery`

Comment: If you use `res <- dbSendQuery(...)`, you "must"  call  `dbClearResult(res)`. Alternatively, you can use `dbExecute(...)` without needing to clear the result. (I use quotes around "must" because I believe without doing it, it may be auto-cleared ... not certain if it gathers up or retains any resources.)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the info. I've updated the post.