# Loading Images via readBin

Tags: r, image

I've generated PNG-Images in filesystem which I want to load and view in R-Studio in the first step. Second step is writing them into database as blobs. Reading and writing the images works but the structure of the image seems gone already after `readBin`. The original image had 15698 Bytes, later on in DB or when I write back via `writeBin` it's 32768 Bytes. I've checked many possible ways to use `readBin` but after reading in it's not an image anymore. What do I miss here? Thanks

```
    fileName <- "S:\\Filename.png"
    plotBinary <- paste(readBin(fileName, what="raw", size = NA_integer_, endian = .Platform$endian, n=1e6), collapse="")
    
    query <- paste0("REPLACE INTO Images (Time, Image) VALUES ", "(\"", c(Sys.time()), "\", \"", plotBinary, "\")")
    con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), dbname = "db1")
    result <- dbSendStatement(con, query)
    dbClearResult(result)
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not an image any more"? How exactly are you checking that? What line specifically is causing this problem? Is it just the first two lines that don't work? This seems difficult to help you because it requires setting up an Maria database just to do any testing. What exactly does the contents of `query` look like? I would guess you don't want to use `paste()` on a `raw` vector. That will turn it into a string and completely change the number of bytes.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285267/r-dbgetquery-insert-blob-data-with-other-text-data. Better to use `dbExecute` with parameters than `dbSendStatement` to get the encoding correct.

Comment: The `paste` is from an `r-bloggers` article, where someone is doing almost the same what I try to achieve and w/o it I couldn't store it in the database. So I had no doubt about the `paste`. But after your comment I double checked and leaving it out then it is an image, meaning saving it back to file system the image can be viewed. For the second part (storing img in DB) I already was thinking which of the both db-methods would be more useful. I will check your linked answer in detail, Thank You